# CSS: Navigation Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

Building a website for my company, first one. And I’m having trouble getting the navigation bar to be horizontal, and placed in the top right corner of the browser.

The whole top section is a `<div>` (similar to the StackExchange site), and I currently have three elements floating to the top left (`logo`, `name`, `tagline`).

I’m trying to get the navigation bar horizontal and floating to the right, except I can’t locate it there. It keeps appearing outside of the black bar, and beneath the three left floating elements.

HTML code:

```html
    <div class="part1 header">
            <div class="headcontain">
                <a href="http://www.se7enservice.com">

                    <div class="logo"><img src="/Images/7serviceLOGOblue2.png"/></div>
                    <div class="headtag"><img src="/Images/title.png"</div>
                    <div class="tagline"><img src="/Images/tag_line.png"/></div>
                </a>

              <!--  <div class="bif">
                    <div class="bif2">
                        <div id="p1" class="block"></div>
                        <div id="p2" class="block"></div>
                    </div>
                </div> -->

                <ul class="navi">

                    <li><a href='http://www.se7enservice.com/' class="here">Home</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/about.html" >About</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/services.html" >Services</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/pricing.html" >Pricing</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/contact_us.html" >Contact Us</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS code for the three left floating elements and the navigation thus far:

```css
.part1 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  z-indez: 9999;
  height: 60px;
  top: 0px;
}
.logo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  overflow: visible
}
.logo img {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.5px
}
.headtag {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  width: 215px;
  float: left
}
.headtag img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px
}
.tagline {
  width: 220px;
  float: left;
  margin: -50px 0px 0px 220px;
}
.tagline img {
  width: 100%
}
navi {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding: 0px
}
.navi li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It’s completely frustrating. If you would like reference as to what I’m trying to do, refer to http://johnnycupcakes.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style your `li` so they are `display:inline;`. They will sit side by side. Also you need to remove your `float:left` on the `li`;

```
.navi li{
display: block;
position: relative;
/*float: left;*/
margin: 0px 5px;
overflow: hidden;
display:inline;
}
```

You were also missing a closing tag on your `img`;

```
 <div class="part1 header">
            <div class="headcontain">
                <a href="http://www.se7enservice.com">

                    <div class="logo"><img src="/Images/7serviceLOGOblue2.png"/></div>
                    <div class="headtag"><img src="/Images/title.png"/></div><!--Closed image tag-->
                    <div class="tagline"><img src="/Images/tag_line.png"/></div>
                </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `<div class="headtag"><img src="/Images/title.png"</div>` has to be changed to

`<div class="headtag"><img src="/Images/title.png"/></div>` you forgot to close off the image tag.

as well as this, change your css to the following:

```
.part1{
width: 100%;
float: left;
background: #000;
position: fixed;
z-indez: 9999;
height: 60px;
top: 0px;
}
.logo,.headtag,.tagline{ 
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:green;
}
.logo {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
float: right;
overflow: visible;
}

.logo img {
width: 100%;
padding: 1.5px
}

.headtag {
padding: 0px 10px;
width: 215px;
float: right;
}

.headtag img {
width: 100%;
}

.tagline {
width: 220px;
float: right;
}

.tagline img {
width: 100%
}

navi {
list-style: none;
float: right;
margin: 0px;
margin-left: 25px;
padding: 0px
}

.navi li{
display: block;
position: relative;
float: left;
margin: 0px 5px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lmafwgh/)

Comment: This worked as well. Damn syntax, that closing tag fixed all of my positioning problems. It did work though! However I'm now converting Jordan above code since it's more legible. Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick... let me know if this is what your looking for.

//HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div>
            <div id="logo">LOGO</div>
        </div>
        <div> 
            <a href='http://www.se7enservice.com/' class="here">Home</a>
            <a href="/about.html" >About</a>      
            <a href="/services.html" >Services</a>          
            <a href="/pricing.html" >Pricing</a>    
            <a href="/contact_us.html" >Contact Us</a>      
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="">Sign Up</a>
            <a href="">Sign In</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section id="content"></section>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

//CSS

```
body{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;

    margin: 0 !important;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;

    overflow: scroll;

}

nav{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    width: 100%;
    min-height: 60px;

    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;
    background: #1E67CB;

    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
nav>div{
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;

    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self: center; 
}
#logo{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self: center;

    margin-left: 1em;

    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    line-height: 1.43;  
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: Circular,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
nav>div{
    width: 50vw;    
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
nav>div:nth-of-type(1){
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
nav>div:nth-of-type(2){
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
nav>div:nth-of-type(3){
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

nav>div>a{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self: center;

    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;

    margin: 0 .5em;
    padding: 0.6em 1.5em;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-transition: background-color 100ms;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 100ms;
    transition: background-color 100ms;
}
nav>div>a:hover{
     background: rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
}
nav>div>a:active{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
nav>div:nth-of-type(3)>a:nth-of-type(2){
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);  
}
nav>div>a:nth-of-type(2):hover{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);  
}
#content{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200vh;
}
footer{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;

    background: #5c5c5c;

    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.6); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is fantastic, and looks so much better and cleaner than what I normally had. Only thing I have no used for is the Sign In and Sign Up, so I'l removing that. And now just looking to shift the actually navigation to align on the right side

Comment: Problem Solved by just removing the Sign In/Sign Up. Thank you! This is amazing!

Comment: @blackRob4953 awesome glad I can help! Let me know if you need help with anything else.

Comment: There is more actually. However code is extremely long. It's for an image gallery, exactly like the website I referenced. Anyway we can email or is that not allowed here?

Comment: @blackRob4953 you can email me "jordan@jordandavis.work" or just create another question and send me the link, trying to get my rep higher.

Comment: I'll try the link. It's only temp files tho. Will the .html/css docs work? It's not a live site, if so how do I do that?

Comment: @blackRob4953 no I meant post the HTML/CSS in another question and tag the link here in the comments and I'll answer it in next question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837995/html-css-photo-gallery-not-displaying-pictures

Comment: How can I turn one of these links ex: 'About.php' page, into a list? I'm trying to get a dropdown menus so I can have 2 option under the about tab @jordandavis